# Simple Lightbox Example in Quarto

Tags: lightbox, quarto

I've created a minimal example to troubleshoot a problem encountered with the [Lightbox extension](https://github.com/quarto-ext/lightbox) to [Quarto](https://quarto.org/).

The current error is

```
GET: /lightbox.html
Error running filter _extensions/quarto-ext/lightbox/lightbox.lua:
_extensions/quarto-ext/lightbox/lightbox.lua:113: attempt to call a nil value (field 'is_format')
stack traceback:
```

(There is nothing listed after "stack traceback".)

I've tried to replicate the "Simple Lightbox Example" from https://github.com/quarto-ext/lightbox.

I get this error when I try to render...

- the book's lightbox.qmd through VS Code (using `quarto preview`, and several variations)
- the stand-alone not-in-the-book.qmd through VS Code (using `quarto preview`, and several variations)
- the book's lightbox.qmd through RStudio (using the "Render button)
- the stand-alone not-in-the-book.qmd through RStudio (using the "Render button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading to [this week's version of Quarto](https://quarto.org/docs/download/) (v1.2.269) fixed the problem.